# is there any way in mongodb to create "user" that have "read" access only to specific views of the db?

Tags: mongodb

I am have created some of views that JSON i want to provide to frontend developers. i want front-end developer to access this views only. not the entire collection or database. this views contains cross-collection "$lookup" aggregations.

how could we create user with roles that have only access to "views" of the "db" only not even "collections"?

Comment: From permission a collection is the same as a view. Just grant 'find' on it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i did not find "find" permission if possible may you share the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions in MongoDB are based on roles. Would be like this:

```
const admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
admin.createRole({ role: "read_views", privileges: [], roles: [] }) 
admin.grantPrivilegesToRole("read_views", [
   { 
       resource: { db: "<database name>", collection: "<view name>" }, 
       actions: ["find"] 
   }
])
```